# Trouble upgrading Ruby on Rails from version 3.2.13 to 4.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4, upgrade, globalize3

For a my application I am trying to upgrade Ruby on Rails from version `3.2.13` to `4.0.0` and I am in trouble when installing / updating some gem (by using the Bundler), specifically the [globalize3](https://github.com/svenfuchs/globalize3) gem. I am running Ruby `2.0.0-p247`.

Given my `Gemfile` is:

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

gem 'globalize3', github: 'svenfuchs/globalize3', branch: 'rails4'

gem 'delayed_job', :git => 'git://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job.git', :branch => 'master'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record', :git => 'git://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_active_record.git', :branch => 'master'

# Added these gems to help with the transition to rails4:
gem 'protected_attributes'
gem 'rails-observers'
gem 'actionpack-page_caching'
gem 'actionpack-action_caching'
gem 'activerecord-deprecated_finders'
```

When I run the `bundle install` command in the Terminal window

Then I get the following output:

```
Updating git://github.com/svenfuchs/globalize3.git
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:
    globalize3 (>= 0) ruby depends on
      activerecord (~> 3.0) ruby

    delayed_job_active_record (>= 0) ruby depends on
      activerecord (4.0.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    globalize3 (>= 0) ruby depends on
      rails (~> 3) ruby

    rails (4.0.0)
```

When I run the `bundle update` command in the Terminal window

Then I get the following output:

```
Updating git://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job.git
Updating git://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_active_record.git
Updating git://github.com/svenfuchs/globalize3.git
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    globalize3 (>= 0) ruby depends on
      rails (~> 3) ruby

    rails (4.0.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    globalize3 (>= 0) ruby depends on
      railties (~> 3.0) ruby

    coffee-rails (~> 4.0.0) ruby depends on
      railties (4.0.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.0.0) ruby depends on
      actionpack (= 4.0.0) ruby

    actionpack-action_caching (>= 0) ruby depends on
      actionpack (4.0.0.rc2)
```

How can I solve the problem? Is the `globalize3` gem really compatible with Ruby on Rails 4? Is it advisable to wait for upgrading to Ruby on Rails 4?

*Note*: I seen the [#415 Upgrading to Rails 4](http://railscasts.com/episodes/415-upgrading-to-rails-4) railscast and I made many searches on the Internet (the most reasonable discussion is "[Globalize3 does not work with Rails4](https://github.com/globalize/globalize/issues/196)") about the problem, but I am still in trouble.

Comment: Hi Backo, can you please provide some material or steps to upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `globalize3` gem has been renamed [`globalize`](http://rubygems.org/gems/globalize) and major version numbers now correspond to the corresponding version of ActiveRecord (3.x for AR3 and 4.x for AR4).

So all you need to do is put this in your Gemfile, and you should not get any conflict:

```
gem 'globalize', '~> 4.0.0.alpha.2'
```

See also the [github repository](https://github.com/globalize/globalize) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try using rails4 branch to avoid upgrading issue.

```
gem 'globalize3', git: 'https://github.com/svenfuchs/globalize3.git', branch: 'rails4'
```

However, you may still meet some issues, because it's not stable branch.