# Globalize and Rails 4: Compatibility status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, upgrade, globalize3

In a my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17750786/trouble-upgrading-ruby-on-rails-from-version-3-2-13-to-4-0-0) (asked about 2 months ago) I was trying to upgrade Ruby on Rails from version 3.2.13 to 4.0.0, without success because the [globalize3](https://github.com/globalize/globalize) ruby-gem compatibility. Today I'm trying again to do the upgrade, without success because the [globalize3](https://github.com/globalize/globalize) ruby-gem compatibility.

I tried all possible solutions that I found on the web (even those that refer to the [rails4 branch](https://github.com/globalize/globalize/tree/rails4)) but no one works for me: I get error outputs as-like those present in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17750786/trouble-upgrading-ruby-on-rails-from-version-3-2-13-to-4-0-0). However, as you can read [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:8rlvqBcD0C8J:https://github.com/svenfuchs/globalize3/issues/196%20&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk), it *seems* that someone (lucky, maybe) has solved the compatibility issue. I am not a "lucky" one and, since I aim to use features added by Rails 4 and still use globalize3, I would like to know if there is someone running Rails 4 and the globalize3 with success. If so, what did he / she made to make that?

What is the compatibility status between globalize3 and Rails 4?

---

*Note*: I also opened a issue at [github](https://github.com/globalize/globalize/issues/279).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using it with rails 4 and have no issue.

In my Gemfile:

```
gem 'globalize3', github: 'svenfuchs/globalize3', branch: 'rails4'
```

Run bundle update instead of bundle install to resolve all dependencies again. Just lock gems that you don't want updated by indicating a version specifier as explained here http://bundler.io/v1.3/gemfile.html.

Comment: fatal: ambiguous argument 'rails4': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.